# Don't want the vertical scrollbar in dropdown list

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I do not want the vertical scrollbar to appear for the dropdown list. I want to show all the items. How do I do that ?

size attribute doesn't work.

code design:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTables" CssClass="labels" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                    AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="230px"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTables_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

[image]

Comment: who can read 50 options at once? consider the user in your design. If displaying 50 items at once is absolutely necessary, perhaps reduce the text size or maybe the dropdown format is not the ideal solution

Comment: Not 50, we have 34.. font size is a little small, still vertical scrollbar appears. But that's what the users want :-/

Answer (score 1):

The Scrollbar is there because you have too many items or too few height. Assuming you want to keep all the items there, you need to set `this.size`  attribute to a value which will show all of the items without scrolling:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTables" 
                  CssClass="labels" 
                  runat="server" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                  Width="230"
                  onMouseOver="this.size=50;" 
                  onMouseOut="this.size=1;"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTables_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: is there a way we can do the same on click of dropdownlist control ?

Comment: ok, i tried to set size to 50 onClick but it flickers. it shows scrollbar for microseconds and then shows full list.. way to fox that ?

Comment: Did you keep the `onMouseOver` too after adding `onclick`?

Comment: No, i removed onMouseOver, onMouseout was there .

Comment: @Sak try adding it back and let me know.

Comment: but I don't need onMouseOver functionality.. i need to click and display the list